# Subtly resizing elements that use Bootstrap grid classes

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, resize

I'm trying to make a website that uses bootstrap's grid systems as a guide, but isn't ruled by it, to the point of looking too similar to other websites, and having all my elements either too close to each other, or too far apart, which tends to happen with the most basic usages of the  12 column layout.

Now, I know I could change the number of columns to 16 or 24 but with the way I have my project setup that would be difficult and would still be more restrictive than I'd like. So I was wondering, if I have code similar to this:

```
<div class="bean-game col-md-8">
  <h2>Bean Curd Mixing Area</h2>
</div>
```

Without using the `width:` CSS property, or anything that overrides the Bootstrap CSS completely (which I'm concerned might make the code unmanageable in other ways), is there anything I can do with CSS, or perhaps even JavaScript or a JS library if need be, to make the`.bean-game` div resize *relative* to the width set in the Bootstrap code for the `col-md-8` class?

In the case of the website I'm working on, I'd like the div bearing a `col-md-8` class to be just a fraction wider (say 10px or so), so as to neatly align with the div above it, which, despite bearing another `col-md-[foo]` class is just outside the usual grid-system due to some minor trickery with a container div and some margins, which gave me a spacing effect I was after...

I realise this may be a difficult thing to be trying to do, but it really feels like the best way to approach this particular issue.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ - you can build your own!  Enjoy

Comment: yeah, I saw that, but this is a more complex solution than I was hoping for and is a bit off a hammer-to-crack-a-nut situation, given the variations I want on the grid system are comparatively minor at this stage and I have a vast raft of other work as well. At least to my current understanding of the proffered solution. What I'll probably do is resize on initialisation with JS, which I *think* should be possible, though it doesn't separate language and function the way I'd like, but sometimes needs must I guess. I'll take another look at customization too though. And thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look into this and it seems the best solution for me at present will be using pseudo-classes (probably `::after` though I haven't played around with them enough yet...) to add pseudo-padding and therefore get around the Bootstrap limitations on the fly, without have to customise my entire Bootstrap setup (which I prefer leaving on a CDN,) and without having to dirty the relation between form and function by having my JavaScript perform styling operations unrelated to user input. It's still not a 'perfect' solution, but I may use it as an opportunity to introduce some slightly more advanced styling, which will hopefully benefit the overall page aesthetic.

I will accept my own answer if this solution works out to my satisfaction.